# How to download multiple URLs using wget using a single command?

Tags: windows, download, wget

I am using following command to download a single webpage with all its images and js using `wget` in Windows 7:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html
```

It is downloading the HTML as required, but when I tried to pass on a text file having a list of 3 URLs to download, it didn't give any output, below is the command I am using:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i ./list.txt -B 'http://'
```

I tried this also:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i ./list.txt
```

This text file had URLs `http://` prepended in it.

`list.txt` contains list of 3 URLs which I need to download using a single command. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: on a unix bash you can always put multiple commands on one line like: wget google.com && wget nytimes.com For windows see http://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline

Comment: @mb21 There is no way to get it done by providing it a list in a text file?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From [`man wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Invoking):

> 2 Invoking
> By default, Wget is very simple to invoke. The basic syntax is:
> wget [option]... [URL]...

So, just use multiple URLs:

```
wget URL1 URL2
```

Or using the links from comments:

```
$ cat list.txt
http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html
http://www.verizonwireless.com/smartphones-2.shtml
http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html
```

and your command line:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/ -i ./list.txt
```

works as expected.

Comment: I am getting `http is not recognized as an internal and external command` error with this.

Comment: Finally, I am using `wget URL1 URL2` method, but do tell me if more efficient method is there.

Answer (score 23):

First create a text file with the URLs that you need to download.
eg: download.txt

`download.txt` will as below:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

then use the command `wget -i download.txt` to download the files. You can add many URLs to the text file.

Comment: I have created a txt file which has 3 following links : `http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html
http://www.verizonwireless.com/smartphones-2.shtml
http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html` After executing it is saying that `No URLs found in list.txt`

Comment: did you add those URLs in seperate lines?

Comment: Yeah, they were in separate lines.

Comment: But i am able to download from the URL that you provide me with the same method i have mentioned above.I think you are not running the command from the correct path.you should run from the same path where you created download.txt file.      Here i have created download.txt in "D" directory and running the command from "D" itself.

Comment: Here is my command line:`PS D:\> wget -i download.txt`            
--2013-01-29 17:37:50--  http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html
Resolving www.vodafone.de... 139.7.147.41
Connecting to www.vodafone.de|139.7.147.41|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 137081 (134K) [text/html]
Saving to: red-smartphone-tarife.html
100%[=====================>] 137,081     75.4K/s   in 1.8s
2013-01-29 17:37:53 (75.4 KB/s) - `red-smartphone-tarife.html' saved [137081/137081]
FINISHED --2013-01-29 17:37:53--
Downloaded: 1 files, 134K in 1.8s (75.4 KB/s)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of URLs separated on multiple lines like this:

```
http://example.com/a
http://example.com/b
http://example.com/c
```

but you don't want to create a file and point wget to it, you can do this:

```
wget -i - <<< 'http://example.com/a
http://example.com/b
http://example.com/c'
```

Answer (score 0):

pedantic version:

```
for x in {'url1','url2'}; do wget $x; done
```

the advantage of it you can treat is as a single wget url command