# Best method for bulk downloading images from website

Tags: php, image, curl

I will download a lot of images (+20.000) from a website to my server and i'm trying to figure out the best way to do this since there's so many images to download.

Currently I have the code below which works in testing. But is there a better solution or should I use some software to do this?

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

$url = $product->img;
$imgName = $product->product_id
$path = "images/";

$img =  $path . $imgName . ".png";

file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));

}
```

Also, is there a chance that I will break something or crash the website when I download that many images at once?

Comment: If your codes is already working, and you just want a review, you will get help better in [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, i agree with @Rudy Palacois here, wget would probably be better. that said, if you want to do it in PHP, curl would be much faster than file_get_contents, for 2 reasons.

1: unlike file_get_contents, curl can reuse the same connection to download multiple files, while file_get_contents will create & close a new connection for each download, that takes time, thus curl will be faster (as long as you're not using CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE / CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT , anyway)

2: curl stops the download when the `Content-Length` http header's bytes has been downloaded. but file_get_contents completely ignores this header, and keeps downloading everything it can, until the connection is closed. this can again be much slower than curl's approach, because it's up to the web server when the connection will close, on some servers, it's A LOT slower than reading Content-Length bytes.

(and generally, curl is faster than file_get_contents because curl supports compressed transfers, gzip and deflate, which file_get_contents does not do... but that's generally not applicable for images, most common image formats are already pre-compressed. notable exceptions include `.bmp` images, though)

like this:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' ); // if you're downloading files that benefit from compression (like .bmp images), this line enables compressed transfers.
foreach ( $products as $product ) {

    $url = $product->img;
    $imgName = $product->product_id;
    $path = "images/";

    $img = $path . $imgName . ".png";
    $img=fopen($img,'wb');
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_FILE => $img 
    ) );
    curl_exec ( $ch );
    fclose($img);
    // file_put_contents ( $img, file_get_contents ( $url ) );
}
curl_close ( $ch );
```

edit: fixed a code-breaking typo, it's called `CURLOPT_FILE`, not `CURLOPT_OUTFILE`

edit 2: CURLOPT_FILE wants a file resource, not a filepath, fixed that too x.x

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method and it's much faster than file_put_contents. Another question I was thinking about (probobly stupid), can this method crash or make some damage to the server with the pictures when downloading +20.000 images? I have their approval to use the pictures but I don't want to crash anything on their site.

Comment: @mattjon the short answer is no. the long answer includes `well, it's theoretically possible` - if they run out of RAM or disk space or something like that, if you, say, have a memory leak bug in your code, and all the images you download are stored in memory all at once, you could cause out-of-memory crashes.. or if you use up all their harddrive space, anything that needs to write to disk could crash... but no.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to shell, you could use WGET, I mean, the main problem with php, if you are executing this code from a browser, is the execution time, it will stop after a few minutes or it can be loading forever and get stucked, but if you have a complete URL and a pattern, as I can see, you can create a file with the URLs, one URL per line, list.txt, for example and then execute

```
wget -i list.txt
```

Check this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578517/5415074

Comment: the execution time is not a problem with php. just do `set_time_limit(0);ignore_user_abort(true);`, and you got unlimited time. or run php from cli, and the time limit doesn't even apply. however, if you're running php behind a webserver, loading the script from a browser, the browser will timeout eventually, but curl won't, so call it with curl, then you'll know when the script has finished. another thing is that the webserver gateway might timeout eventually (like nginx will timeout after 120 seconds by default, i believe)

Comment: You could use `exec()`, this PHP function allows you to execute shell command via PHP, but sometime it's disabled, you can check if you can use it writting `<?php exec('mkdir newfolder') ?>` and then verify via FTP if a new folder called **"newfolder"** was created in the same directory you ran the PHP, @hanshenrik suggestion is a very good alternative too if you can't use shell commands via exec() either.