# Tool to run http requests

Tags: http, request, http-headers

I'm looking for a tool to which I can feed a file of saved http requests with their respective headers and the tool executes it. I mean, is there something that does that without the need of creating a wrapper? I know I could easily achieve this in any language, but that's not the question in this case. I know Postman, Insomnia, etc, but not quite sure whether I can open a file with HTTP requests and if so what should be the delimiter per request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download multiple urls using wget using a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578264/how-to-download-multiple-urls-using-wget-using-a-single-command)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110444/how-to-run-multiple-curl-requests-processed-sequentially